# Where do I place a WHERE clause in a PIVOT with date transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
amount_usd  paytype SendItemDateTime1
5.00    google  2015-04-01
2.00    google  2015-04-01
5.00    transfer    2015-04-01
15.00   google  2015-04-01
5.00    google  2015-04-01
2.00    google  2015-04-02
60.00   google  2015-04-02
60.00   google  2015-04-02
5.00    google  2015-04-03
```

Above is my demo database which have amount_usd, paytype, and SendItemDateTime1 column. when i using pivok with query below, it come out result below, which the SendItemDateTime1 is not group by... what is the problem?

```
 select amount_usd, paytype, SendItemDateTime1 from tblMobile_RequestOrderLog
  where status = 1 and sendstatus = 1 and enable = 1
  and SendItemDateTime1  between '4/1/2015' and '4/30/2015'
  order by SendItemDateTime1
```

Below is the result from query above.

```
SenditemDateTime1   google  mol molpay  molstore    paypal  transfer
2015-04-01  15.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-04-01  5.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-04-01  15.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-04-01  5.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-04-01  60.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-04-01  10.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And below is what i want...

```
SendItemDate    google  mol molpay  molstore    paypal  transfer
2015-04-01      32      0   0       0          0    5
2015-04-02      122     0   0       0          0    0
2015-04-03      5       0   0       0          0    0
```

sorry, first time post question here...

**Edit**

This work for me with "Where" clause:

```
SELECT SendItemDateTime1, COALESCE([google], 0), COALESCE([transfer], 0),
       COALESCE([paypal], 0),COALESCE([molpay], 0)
FROM (Select SendItemDateTime1, paytype, amount_usd 
      from tblMobile_RequestOrderLog
      where gameidn = 248 and status = 1 and sendstatus = 1 and enable = 1 
            and SendItemDateTime1 between '4/1/2015 12:00:00 AM'
                                      and '4/30/2015 11:59:59'
) X 
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amount_usd)
  for [paytype] IN ([google],[transfer],[paypal],[molpay])
) piv;
```

Comment: Have you posted the correct query - there is no PIVOT in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the data in your first table with the below query - you'll just need to list all the payment type columns explicitly. I've assumed `SUM()` as the aggregation to be applied:

```
SELECT SendItemDateTime1, [google],[transfer],[paypal],[molpay]
FROM MyTable
PIVOT
(
 SUM(amount_usd)
 for [paytype] IN ([google],[transfer],[paypal],[molpay])
) piv;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56eb1/6)

**Edit, Re where do I filter**

If the filter predicate can be applied to the final columns, then `WHERE` can be applied after the PIVOT. Otherwise, if the filtering needs to be done in unpivoted columns, then you can use a CTE, or derived table as you have done. Here's an example of prefilter in CTE and postfilter WHERE:

```
-- Prefilter of non-pivot columns done in CTE or Derived table
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT [amount_usd], [paytype], [SendItemDateTime1]
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [amount_usd] > 2
)
SELECT SendItemDateTime1, COALESCE([google], 0), COALESCE([transfer], 0),
       COALESCE([paypal], 0),COALESCE([molpay], 0)
FROM cte
PIVOT
(
 SUM(amount_usd)
 for [paytype] IN ([google],[transfer],[paypal],[molpay])
) piv
-- Post filter of pivot columns done on the final projection
WHERE SendItemDateTime1 > '2015-01-01';
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56eb1/23)

Comment: If you want to map NULLs to Zero, use [COALESCE on the projected columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56eb1/9)

Comment: Thanks StuartLC, this query work for me. but how about adding "Where" command? Becasue MyTable still have other column other than SendItemDateTime1, [google],[transfer],[paypal],[molpay] .